# Difference between single mixture gaussian and regular gaussian distribution

Tags: gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am reading a paper, and it is said "state observationprobability densities were single mixture Gaussian observation densities". My question is: Isn't a single mixture gaussian the same that a regular 1-D gaussian?

Comment: I single mixture sounds to me like a mixture of two different Gaussian distributions which may not look like a single Gaussian distribution at all.  It is likely to be bimodal.  The existence of a mean and covariance matrix can happen with a mixture distribution without it being a single Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Single mixture gaussian does not seem to be an accepted term, but it is probably equivalent to a regular gaussian distribution, either univariate or multivariate (more context is needed to tell which).

Without knowing which paper you are talking about, I would guess that the authors modeled state observation distribution as a single gaussian, but wanted to hint that the model *could* be generalized to a gaussian mixture with $n > 1$ components, even though they did not do so.

edit: [paper is here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kevin_Englehart/publication/225028764_Continuous_multifunction_myoelectric_control_using_pattern_recognition/links/5745f7dc08ae9ace84243523/Continuous-multifunction-myoelectric-control-using-pattern-recognition.pdf)

After reading the context in the paper, I am more confident that the authors intended single mixture gaussian to just mean a normal gaussian distribution, as they talk about a single mean and covariance matrix.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't the author talking here about a multivariate gaussian with every dimension being the dimension of the feature vector (in this case, 6 AR coefficients and RMS, so dimension 7)?